# Apache install on Windows, cannot find installer

Tags: windows, apache

I'm trying for a couple of hours to find a MSI or EXE install package for Apache in Windows, and simply could not find it anywhere. All i get is a zip file with the directory structure, but when i extract it obviously the service is not installed / configured.

Can someone please point me to a place where i can find a MSI installer pro Win 2008 / 64bit ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why there are several packages including WAMP, XAMPP etc because it must be compiled and Apache will not provide binaries.

> The Apache HTTP Server Project itself does not provide binary releases
>   of software, only source code.

A quick search would reveal some sources where you can download load them. I suggest to go with one of these to make maintaining it easier for yourself.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#down

Here are some suggestions as noted in the docs.

```
ApacheHaus
Apache Lounge
BitNami WAMP Stack
WampServer
XAMPP
```

Edit:

I do not know specifically where you can get 2.4 msi and there may not be but 2.2 is still available if you have to have an installer. Which is still the most used version. Which is what I run on all my servers. Get 2.2.25

https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/win32/

If you want 2.4 for windows which is NEWER that is the correct package from Apache Lounge you don't need an installer. The package give you the exact layout for the web sever. You're looking for a pretty little msi that goes through a wizard like WAMP, you're not going to find that. Installing from that zip you downloaded is easy and only takes like 5 minutes to setup. You can also put httpd.exe in the windows startup to so that it starts when it boots. Watch this video, it walks your through setting 2.4 up.

http://www.lynda.com/Apache-HTTP-Server-tutorials/Installing-Apache-HTTP-Server-24-Windows-New/77958/150487-4.html

Comment: In all these places i don't get a installer, i get a ZIP file with the folder structure (bin, cgi-bin, conf and so on). What i want is a installer, that will install the service, just as Wamp does, but i don't want Wamp because i only need Apache, no MySql / PHP. What am i missing here ?